# How to obfuscate my code with proguard?

Tags: java, proguard, lwjgl, obfuscation

I'm trying to obfuscate my java code with [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) (5.2.1).
I'm using LWJGL in my project.

So i execute proguardgui.jar and when the window is open, i do :
- Click on "Input / Output."
- CLick on "Add input" (choose my jar file etc...)
- CLick on "Add output" (type "PWdd.jar" etc...)
- Click on "Next" (5 times)
- Click on "Process!"

That's the answer of the program :
http://whiteplay.fr/help.html (I had to make an html page because StackOverflow have a limit of lines in each questions :/)
Do you know what have i to do ?
PS : The program (The input jar file) is working before the obfuscation.

Comment: http://crunchify.com/how-to-convert-existing-java-project-to-maven-in-eclipse/ and https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Comment: Thanks @specializt, I instaled maven and convert my eclipse project. But when i'm trying to add LWJGL'jar with this method : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-in-maven-project, it dont works. Can you help me ? (Maybe we should find another place to chat).

Comment: @John sorry to confuse you, that was not an answer just hint for pasting big chunks of logs etc.. you dont have to create web pages for that :) just use pastebin site

Comment: Ah ok @otopolsky, i just doesn't understant :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, because i used eclipse, when i exported my jar file, i choosed to include jar lib to my jar projetc. If you choose to put them into a folder neer the project jar it's working :D

Answer (score 0):

Super late, but I did have the same issue today and figured it out

1. Export jar with separate folder for libraries (call it `jar1.jar` for example)
2. Obfuscate `jar1.jar` to `jar1_obf.jar`
3. Export again with libraries extracted in jar file (`jar2.jar`)
4. rename `jar1_obf.jar` to `jar_obf.zip`
5. rename `jar2.jar` to `zip2.zip`
6. extract `zip1.zip` to `folder1`
7. extract `zip2.zip` to `folder2`
8. copy all files and files not found in `folder1` from `folder2` to `folder1` (do not copy everything and paste, because there is a chance that an unnecessary file is copied into `folder1`)
9. now that `folder1` has everything, send all the contents (not `folder1` itself) of `folder1` to `final.zip`
10. rename `final.zip` to `final.jar` with jar extension, it should work!
11. Delete any files and folders created in the process (except `final.jar` of course)

Hopefully, this made sense; it probably got confusing with all the file names.